# Where can I find the number of add-ons for each category in the Google Sheets Add-ons store?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-addons

I would like to know the number of add-ons for each category (Business Tools, Productivity, ...) in the add-on store of Google Sheets.

What I tried:

1. I opened a new spreadsheet.
2. I opened the add-on store from the menu.
3. I select one of the categories which lists a number of add-ons without giving me any further information about the number of items in each category.

[image: add-on store]

Comment: I think that you should use javascript on the browser Developers Tools Console to count, in a similar way that was done on the following answer from [so] to find the table index to be used on IMPORTHTML : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313779/how-can-i-find-out-what-index-is-the-table-i-want-to-import-from-a-web-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a hack is possible for one category at a time. Select the category, scroll down to the last entry (no `See More`), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>, then in the top row of a spreadsheet <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>V</kbd>, scroll down to the last entry and read off its row number.

Currently I make it 221 for `Business Tools` and 424 for `Productivity`, for example.